# Azure app service always provide wrong Cache-Control value

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, cache-control, response-headers, azure-appservice

In the .net core application, Value of Cache-Control set to private, max-age=3592001.

```
 app.Use(async (res, next) =>
{                       
     res.Response.Headers.Remove("Cache-Control");
     res.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=3592001");
     await next();
 });
```

But this configuration not reflecting in the browser.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 27 Nov 2021 06:58:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

Cache-Control: public,max-age=2592000
```

Code run from the Visual studio its work fine.

but its hosted in the Azure App Service. It's getting wrong header. Same for the new URL also.

No configuration for *Cache-Control* in the Web.config.

Comment: Cache-Control: Private
The private response directive indicates that a resource is user specific—it can still be cached, but only on a client device. For example, a web page response marked as private can be cached by a desktop browser, but not a content delivery network (CDN).

Comment: Server configuration is private but client side showing public

Comment: Are you using `app.UseResponseCaching()` middleware in startup configuration for the cleint-caching?

Comment: have you been able to solve this problem? I have the same ...